# In Eclipse, is it possible to set annotation processing and factory path by default?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotation-processing, mapstruct

Currently for every project that uses mapstruct in eclipse I have to go:

> Configure Build Path > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Factory Path

and check "use project specific settings" and configure the factory path to use the mapstruct processor jar manually every time.

The phrase *"use project specific settings"* kind of alludes to a global setting somewhere, but I was unable to find anything like this under Preferences.

**Is there some place I can configure the default behavior for annotation processing?**

Answer (score 2):

I followed the recomendation of Filip but I couldn't make Eclipse add the necessary classpath once the project is imported in the Eclipse workspace. I added the build-helper-maven-plugin in my pom.xml to aid Eclipse adding the desired classpath:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations/</source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

This resulted to the desired classpathentry in .classpath file:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources/annotations">
<attributes>
    <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
    <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Eclipse](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#eclipse) support for MapStruct.

You need add `m2e_apt` to your properties.

```
<properties>
  <!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
  <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
</properties>
```

And also make sure that you have correctly setup the maven-compiler.

We suggest using the `annotationProcessorPaths` option of the maven-compiler-plugin (using it, won't leak the mapstruct processor on your compile path).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <target>1.6</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```